# Vue3: app.component does not show up on page and inspect element

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3

I am trying to implement vue 3 code on html format code inside php blade file and js format.

I have this piece of code as main part that need to show up on web.
I put this code inside `html.blade.php`

```
 <div id="app">
    <test-a></test-a>
 ...
</div>

<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/component-test.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="js/main2.js"></script>
```

inside the `main.js` i have this code, to initiate the `createApp` vue3

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
   ...
})
```

on `component-test.js` I have this code to define component:

```
app.component("test-a", {
    template: '<span style="background: green">test a</span>',

});
```

on `main2.js` I have this code to define component:

```
app.mount('#app');
```

At the moment I want the component `test-a` can show up inside `<div id="app">`. However, it does not show up at all.
And the component does not show up at all on the console vue inspect (Please see the image below). And there is no error on console as well.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

[image: please see the image below]

Comment: Hi ! You haven't posted what is in `<div id="app">` .. so does it contain `<test-a></test-a>`? Are there errors on the console? See also [Vue component registration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration) and [Vue component basics](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics). Notice they tell you to use kebab-case (with the dashes) and closing tags OR PascalCase for component name and tag. Maybe create and compile their tutorials first to see what's the difference?

Comment: Thanks, i added more explanation above. there is no error on console. Unfortunately, those link not helped

Comment: The documentation I linked told you to name the component PascalCase. So `TestA` in your case: `app.component("TestA", { template etc... })`. Have you done that? Work through the examples first. Once you have gotten them to work, then change the names and tag to what you're using to see when it breaks. The examples from the official documentation are certainly correct.

Comment: Yes, I did that, however, my case i need to define the vue3 component inside .js file instead .vue file. And even i implement that it does not work on my case

Comment: Oh okay, your question text just doesn't show that you named the component `TestA` - your code in the question still says `test-a`. BTW you can create a runnable example with the `<>` button in StackOverflow's editor. Maybe that makes it more clear what the issue might be if you followed the tutorials otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Can't run i'm pretty sure because of this if what you provided is correct you have to fix most of the code because you are using ESM module so variables are always scope so different modules cannot access each other . Please correct it as follows:

> Since you are using a module, there is no reason why you should not use vue's iife package

component-test.js -> test-a.js:

```js
import { defineComponent } from "lib/vue.js"

export default defineComponent({
  template: '<span style="background: green">test a</span>'
})
```

app.js

```js
import { createApp } from "lib/vue.js"
import TestA from "./test-a.js"

const app = createApp({
  components: { TestA },
   ...
})

app.mount("#app")
```

html:

```html
 <div id="app">
    <test-a></test-a>
 ...
</div>

<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
```